# Cancel a WMI query from VBS

Tags: vbscript, timeout, wmi

Is there some way to cancel a running WMI query from a VBS script?

If I create a WMI object and I make a query... Can I set a timeout or something like it so it stops after 25secs for example?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timeout for the entire script when launching it:

```
cscript //T:10 C:\path\to\your.vbs
```

but as far as I know setting a timeout for a WMI call is not possible.